# Proof of a Proposition in Logic

Tags: logic

Is it possible to prove the proposition

if $P \land Q \Rightarrow R$

then

$P \land R \Rightarrow \lnot Q $

or in other words

($P \land Q \Rightarrow R)  \Rightarrow (P \land R \Rightarrow \lnot Q )$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $P,Q,R=1$. The first statement is true and the second statement is...

Comment: You should not just answer it for the OP. In this situation, you must only give hints.

Comment: Your answer does not prove anything. I should have been more specific. I've edited the original question. Could you please take another look

Comment: I fixed this above.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would like you to think about the relation between $\cup$ and $\land$, and $\cap$ and $\lor.$ Then, prove this statements using true and false propositional definitions. Once done, you will know how to prove this problem on your own.